# Accessible mode repeating

Tags: android, repeat, accessible, switchpreference

I load different layouts when SwitchPreference is turned on and off, and summay has a countdown when it is turned on, but when I turn on Accessible mode, the words on the countdown screen refresh, causing repeated broadcasts.
I use setLayoutResource() in onPreferenceChange() to load different layouts.